# How to calculate time differences in C++ with time_t before the epoch?

Tags: c++, mktime, time-t, difftime

What I would like to do with my simple program is to calculate a difference in seconds between two dates.

```
time_t referenceDate;
time_t dateNow = time(0);
struct tm referenceDateComponent = {0};
referenceDateComponent.tm_hour = 0;
referenceDateComponent.tm_min = 0;
referenceDateComponent.tm_sec = 0;
referenceDateComponent.tm_year = 89;
referenceDateComponent.tm_mon = 11;
referenceDateComponent.tm_mday = 31;
referenceDate = mktime(&referenceDateComponent);  
long seconds = difftime(dateNow, referenceDate);
```

Whit the code above the application works fine, but if try to set `tm.year` negative (to build a date before 1900) the `mktime()` function return `-1`

I know that `time_t` type manage only dates starting from Jan 1, 1970 UTC according with the documentation:

> For historical reasons, it is generally implemented as an integral value representing the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., a unix timestamp). Although libraries may implement this type using alternative time representations.

I know there are also the `Boost` libraries but is not a usable solution for me.

So my question would be, there is any way to get difference in seconds from dates starting before 1970?

Comment: Can you improve your title? It doesn't describe your question in any useful way.

Comment: What is the actual use case for a date before 1900 on the computer? Is it the birthday of some very old person, or worse than that... Gregorian/Julian transition happened in the XXth century in Russia. So **edit your question** to give context and motivation and more explanations

Comment: [This is not simple at all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: Are you interested in dates before 1970, or dates before 1900?

Comment: @rwong: Much much better. I was hoping to persuade the OP to give it a go him/herself but, thanks anyway!

Comment: thanks @rwong for setting the correct title and point me on it. Sorry,  I was frustrated.

Comment: @SteveSummit sorry i mean 1900. The 1970 was a typo.

Comment: @strstr: Ah, well.  Sorry to hear abut the pre-1900 need. I composed my answer before seeing your reply, so I'm afraid my answer won't be too useful to you, either.

Comment: @nwp: your video link is very funny. I knew more than a half of it!

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using the C++11 `std::chrono` namespace and [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) standard headers and the standard functions and classes inside them.

You might also consider [difftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/) from the C standard and [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) & `mktime`

And there are a *lot of good other reasons to upgrade to [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)* at least (or [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) if you can). Several good recent free software compilers [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) support that standard (compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++14` if you want GNU extensions & C++14)

BTW, your question is much more complex than you believe. Calendars has changed. [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)/[Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) calendar transition happened in the XX<sup>th</sup> century in Russia. My late mother was born in 1919, during emigration and the civil war, in a Russian village whose legal system was disputed at that time (Russian revolution did not occur instantly). She had some papers mentioning 13<sup>th</sup> december 1919, and other papers mentioning 26<sup>th</sup> december 1919, referring to the same date in two different calendars. How would your software deal with that? I'm not even sure that timezone is enough!

<sup>BTW, I'm not sure that *Boost* or C++11 `<chrono>` can *reliably* deal with such calendar issues.</sup>

[nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp) mentioned in a comment a very good [computerphile video: Problem with Time & Timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Answer (score 1):

You've already answered this question. `time_t` represents a number of seconds since the UNIX epoch, not number of seconds since some arbitrary time before that. What you are trying to do fundamentally makes no sense.

If you're stuck on C++03, regardless of your ambiguous claims about what you can and cannot use, you will have to use [*Boost.DateTime*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Otherwise, the standard library has some nice modern timekeeping features in `<chrono>`.

Comment: *"I know there are also the Boost libraries but is not a usable solution for me."*

Comment: OP stated that he cannot use Boost!

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to do calendar arithmetic using `time_t`, you naturally have to worry about the type and representation of `time_t`, which is of course implementation-defined.  It's almost always a signed, integral type.  On Unix and modern MacOS systems it's seconds since 1970, and for compatibility I think it might be used that way on Windows, too.  It tends to be 32 bits.  Putting that all together, it can typically represent dates between December 13, 1901 and January 18, 2038.

And indeed when I changed the `tm_year` line in your code to

```
referenceDateComponent.tm_year = 60;
```

the code worked and printed 1721200226, which is about 19921 days or 54.5 years, which is exactly the difference between December 31, 1960 and today.

But if you set `tm_year` to be negative, you'd be asking for a date before 1900, and that's not going to work using the typical definition of `time_t` we've been discussing.

(It's true there are other possibilities for `time_t`.  It could be floating point.  It could be unsigned instead of signed.  It could be a 64-bit type, meaning it'd have a range of almost 600,000,000,000 years, which is incidentally more than a 32-bit `tm_year` can hold.)

So although there are several naysayers here telling you not to, and although there are certainly plenty of obscure difficulties having to do with time zones and leap seconds and calendars other than Gregorian, you can usually get away with using `time_t` to do basic calendar math for dates in the 20th century and in this century up until 2038, when the infamous "[Y2.038K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)" is going to hit.  (It will, I fear, be somewhat worse than the not-so-infamous [Y2K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem), but that's another story.)

As I said, your code worked for me for dates before 1970.  Here's what I'd recommend using for simple `time_t`-based date calculations (and with caveats as already mentioned):

```
time_t makedate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    struct tm tm = {0};
        tm.tm_hour = 12;
    tm.tm_min = tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = month - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = day;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    return mktime(&tm);
}

int main()
{
    long int d = difftime(makedate(2015, 7, 17), makedate(2015, 6, 1));
    printf("%ld sec = %ld days = %.2f years\n", d, d/86400, d/86400./365.25);

    d = difftime(makedate(2015, 7, 17), makedate(2014, 7, 17));
    printf("%ld sec = %ld days = %.2f years\n", d, d/86400, d/86400./365.25);

    d = difftime(makedate(1975, 7, 17), makedate(1965, 7, 17));
    printf("%ld sec = %ld days = %.2f years\n", d, d/86400, d/86400./365.25);

    d = difftime(makedate(1950, 1, 11), makedate(1925, 1, 1));
    printf("%ld sec = %ld days = %.2f years\n", d, d/86400, d/86400./365.25);

    d = difftime(makedate(2030, 12, 31), makedate(2025, 12, 31));
    printf("%ld sec = %ld days = %.2f years\n", d, d/86400, d/86400./365.25);
}
```

Just like your code, this leverages the surprisingly powerful `mktime` function, and can do everything it can do.  It handles leap years, no problem.  It does not handle leap seconds or calendar changes.

And if, as you say, you're interested in dates before 1900, I'm afraid you're out of luck.  `time_t` simply cannot represent those dates on most systems, so you're going to have to pursue some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gregorian calendar's 400-year periodicity to work with dates before the Epoch. (Of course, you need to be careful about the start of the Gregorian calendar in your country of interest).

Add 400 years to both dates you're comparing so that they are beyond 1970 (the Epoch), normalize with `mktime()`, and compute the difference with `difftime()`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double compare_dates (const struct tm *date_1, const struct tm *date_2)
{
    struct tm normalized_1 = *date_1, normalized_2 = *date_2;
    normalized_1.tm_year += 400, normalized_2.tm_year += 400;
    time_t t1 = mktime(&normalized_1);
    time_t t2 = mktime(&normalized_2);
    return difftime(t1, t2);
}

int main (void)
{
    // how many seconds between June 1st 1880 and 15th September 1892 ?
    struct tm june_1st_1880       = { .tm_mon = 6 - 1, .tm_mday =  1, .tm_year = 1880 - 1900 };
    struct tm september_15th_1892 = { .tm_mon = 9 - 1, .tm_mday = 15, .tm_year = 1892 - 1900 };

    printf("%f seconds", compare_dates(&june_1st_1880, &september_15th_1892));
}
```