# How to achieve time localization in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, localization, date-format

I'm using the `time_t` and `ctime` header to get the time in my app, and it's all OK. The problem is that, the week days and months are displayed in English and i want them to be displayed in my language (Portuguese). How do I do that?

Here's my code:

```
time_t tempo = time(NULL);
char *data = ctime(&tempo);
cout << data << endl;
```

And this is the actual output:

```
"Fri Aug 21 20:00:55 2015"
```

I was thinking in something like this:

```
"20:00:55 Sex 21 Ago 2015"
```

Where Sex is Fri, and Ago is Aug.

I even used this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,".<code_page>");
```

My full code is this (It's in Portuguese, so the variables names can be weird):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <stdlib.h>
void titulo();
int numOrdem(int a);

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;//I'm experimenting with this, and not working...

int main()

{
    int ordem = 0;
    int mesa = 0;
    int turno = 0;
    int quantidade = 0;
    int ordemCheck = 0;
    string anterior = " ";
    string atual;


titulo();

while(true)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
time_t tempo = time(NULL);
char *data = ctime(&tempo);


minhaOrdem:
cout << "Insira o número da ordem: ";
cin >> ordem;
ordemCheck = numOrdem(ordem);
if (ordemCheck < 7 || ordemCheck > 7)
{
    cout << "Ordem incorreta.\n";
    goto minhaOrdem;
}

/*ofstream arquivo;
arquivo.open("ordersOnly.txt", ios::app);
arquivo << ordem << endl;
arquivo.close();

ifstream ler;
ler.open("ordersOnly.txt");

if(ler)
{
    while(ler >> atual)
    {
        if(atual == anterior)
        {
            cout << "Ordem " << atual << " já requisitada!\n";
            goto minhaOrdem;
        }
     anterior = atual;
    }

} Here I'm trying to catch an duplicated value...*/

cout << "Insira a quantidade de peças: ";
cin >> quantidade;

minhaMesa:
cout << "Insira o número da mesa: ";
cin >> mesa;
if(mesa < 1 || mesa > 6)
{
    cout << "Mesa incorreta.\n";
    goto minhaMesa;
}

meuturno:
cout << "Insira seu turno: ";
cin >> turno;
switch (turno)
    {
    case 100:
    break;
    case 200:
    break;
    case 300:
    break;
    default:{cout << "Turno Incorreto.\n";goto meuturno;}
    }
cout << "\n\n";


arquivo.open("ordensDifipro.txt", ios::app);
arquivo << "Ordem: " << ordem << endl;
arquivo << "Quantidade de peças: " << quantidade << endl;
arquivo << "Mesa: RL" << mesa << endl;
arquivo << "Turno: " << turno << endl;
arquivo << "Data: " << data << endl;
arquivo << endl;
arquivo.close();

}//Main while


}// int main


void titulo()
{
  cout << setw(62) << "Requisitor de Ordens - Difipro - v 1.1\n\n\n\n\n";
}

int numOrdem(int a)
{
    int counter = 0;
 while(a > 0)
    {
    a /= 10;
    counter++;
    }
 return counter;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Use `strftime(3)`, which has locale-aware formats.

Comment: If you are using Windows, you should add the appropriate tag for your question.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Your question is OS specific, I'm focusing on Linux and perhaps other POSIX OSes</sup>

You could parse the time string with [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) and convert the time to string with [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), at least if the time fits in a Unix `time_t` (this would always be the case for time between 1970 i.e. the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and 2038 because of the [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)) e.g. using [mktime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) & [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html). Read [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) about some localization & internationalization things. You might need to call [setlocale(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) appropriately.

In C++11 use [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (see also [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)); see [this time_point example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) to start.

Beware that distant times (e.g. early 1900s) can become quite complex, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474558/841108)

Addenda: if you want your date to be in Portuguese, either set your `LANG` or `LC_ALL` environment variable (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)) to `pt_PT.UTF-8` (perhaps by adding `export LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8` in your `~/.bashrc` file on Linux, if your login shell is `bash`) or replace the `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` with `setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_PT.UTF-8");` in your program.

BTW, Windows has its [documentation on `setlocale`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx)

Comment: Can you give me an example on the chrono library? I never used it.

Comment: The documentation of `<chrono>` has several examples

Comment: I'm really new to programming and i couldn't understand anything on the documentation.

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to make my Code::Blocks to run C++11 for 2 weeks straight now and nothing, even though I'm sure i have a compatible compiler! But i guess that's another topic.

Comment: What is your code? Show some significant part of it in some *other* question on Stack Overflow. Give more details (OS, compiler, compilation commands) and motivations.

Comment: All right I can't do another question right now, only in 2 days, but I wrote all the code in there. And I'm using Windows 7 by the way.

Comment: I tried the " setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_PT.UTF-8"); " but it didn't worked.

Comment: Well nothing worked, but I really wanted to thank you for your patience.

Comment: The Windows linked page has links leading to relevant value to be passed to `setlocale`

Comment: You really should not be using locale directly, it makes your code non portable. Basile (and whoever downvoted my Boost answer below) is wrong, this is not an OS specific question if you use the proper portability library. Boost locale is the perfect fit for problems like this. Don't go messing with low level OS specific code for stuff like this, its just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look at the Boost Locale library.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html

Especially the part on formatting and parsing of time formatting:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/locale/doc/html/formatting_and_parsing.html

It allows you to portably output things like date time values using the locale settings of the system it's being run on. There is an example doing exactly what tou are trying to do in a just two lines of code. It also does so without asking you to write platform dependant code. You may want to look at other parts of Boost Locale too, including message translation to make it truly work cross language.

Try to avoid using low level platform API's or C++14 features (as an alternate answer seems to suggest) unless you are sure your code will never be used on an other platform or in a C++ project not using C++11/C++14. Boost mostly is your best bet at writing stuff like this portably.

Comment: Can i ask here another question real quick? I got this message in Code::Blocks when i try to compile an example that I'm trying: "undefined reference to `boost::locale::generator::generator()". How do I fix it?

Comment: You may need to add a -l (or however you add a library to your build in Code::Blocks) for boost_locale .

Comment: Can you  please clarify ?

Comment: The undefined symbol is defined in the library boost_locale so that in order for linking to succeed you need to tell Code::Blocks to link against the boost_locale library. I have no experience with Code::Blocks so I don't know how it lets you define such a thing but in many environments adding ' -l boost_locale ' to the compiler flaga for the final linking compile should so the trick. I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying!